# Defining variable type for google sheets script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm building an arduino project to measure environmental conditions in a salami conditioning cabinet.  I've "stolen" some code from another project.

[https://iotdesignpro.com/articles/esp32-data-logging-to-google-sheets-with-google-scripts#:~:text=Arduino%20Code%20for%20Sending%20Data,it%20into%20the%20Google%20Sheets](https://iotdesignpro.com/articles/esp32-data-logging-to-google-sheets-with-google-scripts#:%7E:text=Arduino%20Code%20for%20Sending%20Data,it%20into%20the%20Google%20Sheets).

However all values that need to be written to the sample google sheet are numbers.  How do I change these values to other data types.
eg:
date
string
boolean values.

This is my code which is working and which puts numeric values in 9 columns in my Google spreadsheet.

```
var sheet_id = "1wZmS30CXD7IJXatestingzmvX9DccLeV4";  
var sheet_name = "cazzzet";  
function doGet(e){  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id);  
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);  
var sensor = Number(e.parameter.sensor);  
var date = Number(e.parameter.date);  
var temp1 = Number(e.parameter.temp1);  
var temp2 = Number(e.parameter.temp2);  
var temp3 = Number(e.parameter.temp3);  
var tempaverage = Number(e.parameter.tempaverage);  
var hg1 = Number(e.parameter.hg1);  
var hg2 = Number(e.parameter.hg2);  
var hg3 = Number(e.parameter.hg3);  
var hgaverage = Number(e.parameter.hgaverage);  
sheet.appendRow([sensor,date,temp1,temp2,temp3,tempaverage,hg1,hg2,hg3,hgaverage]);
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

When you send data to a web app through [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters), they are passed as text strings. With some objects, such as dates and Booleans, you should encode the object as a text string in a format you choose, and decode the text string in your `doGet()` function applying a conversion function that knows how to handle that format.

It is usually easiest to encode dates with [Date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). To decode a date, use the [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) or [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

To encode a Boolean, convert the Boolean to a text string with the [String() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String). To decode a Boolean, test whether it is equal to `'true'`.

Here's an example of how to encode a number, a date, a Boolean and a text string:

```
  const number = String(someNumber);
  const date = someDate.toISOString();
  const boolean = String(someBoolean);
  const string = someString; // no conversion needed
```

And here's how you can decode them:

```
  const someNumber = Number(e.parameter.hg1);
  const someDate = new Date(Date.parse(e.parameter.date));
  const someBoolean = String(e.parameter.temp1).toLowerCase() === 'true';
  const someString = e.parameter.temp2; // no conversion needed
```